# How to avoid using "no data" in image stacking

Tags: python-2.7, image-processing, numpy, gdal

I am new in using python. My problem might seems easy but unfortunately I could not find a solution for it. I have a set of images in Geotiff format which are at the same size, their pixel values range between 0 to 5 and  their non values are -9999. I would like to do kind of image stacking using Numpy and Gdal. I am looking for an stacking algorithm in which those pixels of each image that have a value between 0 to 5 are used and the no data values are not used in computing the average. For example if I have 30 images and for two of them the value at the index Image[20,20] are 2 & 3 respectively and for the rest of images it is -9999 at this index. I want the single band output image to be 2.5 at this index. I am wondering if anyone knows the way to do it?

Any suggestions or hints are highly appreciated.

Edit:
let me clarify it a bit more. Here is a sample :

```
import numpy as np

myArray = np.random.randint(5,size=(3,3,3))
myArray [1,1,1] = -9999

myArray
>> array([[[    0,     2,     1],
           [    1,     4,     1],
           [    1,     1,     2]],

          [[    4,     2,     0],
           [    3, -9999,     0],
           [    1,     0,     3]],

          [[    2,     0,     3],
           [    1,     3,     4],
           [    2,     4,     3]]])
```

suppose that myArray is an ndarray which contains three images as follow:

```
Image_01 = myArray[0]
Image_02 = myArray[1]
Image_03 = myArray[2]
```

the final stacked image is :

```
stackedImage = myArray.mean(axis=0)

>> array([[  2.00000000e+00,   1.33333333e+00,   1.33333333e+00],
          [  1.66666667e+00,  -3.33066667e+03,   1.66666667e+00],
          [  1.33333333e+00,   1.66666667e+00,   2.66666667e+00]])
```

But I want it to be this :

```
array([[  2.00000000e+00,   1.33333333e+00,   1.33333333e+00],
       [  1.66666667e+00,              3.5,   1.66666667e+00],
       [  1.33333333e+00,   1.66666667e+00,   2.66666667e+00]])
```

Comment: I think you can change -9999 to nan, and use `numpy.nanmean()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Masked arrays](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/maskedarray.html) are a good way to deal with missing or invalid values. Masked arrays have a `.data` attribute, which contains the numerical value for each element, and a `.mask` attribute that specifies which values should be considered 'invalid' and ignored.

Here's a full example using your data:

```
import numpy as np

# your example data, with a bad value at [1, 1, 1]
M = np.array([[[    0,     2,     1],
               [    1,     4,     1],
               [    1,     1,     2]],

              [[    4,     2,     0],
               [    3, -9999,     0],
               [    1,     0,     3]],

              [[    2,     0,     3],
               [    1,     3,     4],
               [    2,     4,     3]]])

# create a masked array where all of the values in `M` that are equal to
# -9999 are masked
masked_M = np.ma.masked_equal(M, -9999)

# take the mean over the first axis
masked_mean = masked_M.mean(0)

# `masked_mean` is another `np.ma.masked_array`, whose `.data` attribute
# contains the result you're looking for
print masked_mean.data
# [[ 2.          1.33333333  1.33333333]
#  [ 1.66666667  3.5         1.66666667]
#  [ 1.33333333  1.66666667  2.66666667]]
```

Comment: Thanks @ali_m for the answer. But I am still confused. Please check the edited question, I have tried to clarify it a bit more.

Comment: I've added a full worked example using your input data. I hope this clears things up for you, but if not I'd recommend you read through the docs for `np.ma.masked_array` (linked in my answer).